# Getting list of all Google Drive folders returns only one folder

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm working on some improvement on our google drive integration.
Current state:
There is already implementation of saving files into Google Drive folders using hard-coded folderId. This works with no problems.
Now: I want to extend this logic and I need for this list of all folders.
So I followed this guide:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files
And the problem is that I receive only **one** folder but in google drive there is 10.
Can anyone has any idea what I missed or overlooked? Why result doesn't contain nextPageToken? Spent whole day on it and this drives me crazy. 
This is my method (i'm using service account for connection):

```
@Override
    public List<File> getAllFolders() throws IOException {
        Drive service = googleDriveProvider.getService();

        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

        String pageToken = null;
        do {
            FileList result = service.files().list()
                    .setQ("mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'")
                    .setSpaces("drive")
                    .setSupportsAllDrives(true)
                    .setIncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true)
                    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)")
                    .setPageToken(pageToken)
                    .execute();
            for (File file : result.getFiles()) {
                System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n",
                        file.getName(), file.getId());
            }

            files.addAll(result.getFiles());

            pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
        } while (pageToken != null);

        return files;
    }
```

And this is GoogleDriveProvider:

```
@Service
public class GoogleDriveProvider {
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final Set<String> SCOPES = DriveScopes.all();
    private static final String GET_DRIVE_SERVICE_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Getting instance of Google drive has failed, error: [%s]";

    @Value("${google.drive.service.account.auth.json}")
    private String authJson;

    @Value("${info.app.name}")
    private String appName;


    public Drive getService() throws GoogleDriveException {
        try {
            final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(authJson.getBytes())).createScoped(SCOPES);
            credentials.refreshIfExpired();

            HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

            return new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, requestInitializer)
                    .setApplicationName(appName)
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new GoogleDriveException(
                    format(GET_DRIVE_SERVICE_ERROR_MESSAGE, e.getMessage()), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Total guess: try setting a page size.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Folders must be created by the service account or must be shared with service account first.